# regex in node.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array of array and I want to loop through it and give me all the words without "@", punctuation and hashtag. However my regular expression is removing some of the words completely from the array and I am not sure why.

```
  [ [ '@AIMEEE94x',
      '@Arsenal_Geek',
      '@Charlottegshore',
      'shut',
      'it',
      'ha' ],
     [ '"You',
       'learn',
       'so',
       'much',
       '@MesutOzil1088',
       'and',
       '@Alexis_Sanchez"',
       '-',
       '@alexiwobi:' ] ]


     var regex = /\w+/g;
     var listsb = [];
     for ( i = 0 ; i < tweetsA.length; i++) {
         for(j = 0; j < tweetsA[i].length; j++){

             if (regex.test(tweetsA[i][j])== true){
                 listsb = listsb.concat(tweetsA[i][j])
             }                                                                                                 

         }
     }  
  console.log(listsb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a slight spelling error in your `listsb.length` and were also accessing the Object wrong. Try:

```
var dict = {}; 
for (i = 0; i < listsb.length; i++) {
    if (listsb[i] in dict) {
        dict[listsb[i]] += 1;
    } else {
        dict[listsb[i]] = 1;
    }   

}
console.log(dict);
```

When you want to set an objects key to a string, you need to access it using square bracket notation, such as `myObject[myString]`

Comment: Hi I have  edited the question. Can you please explain where I am going wrong with this?